# converting various bash commands to tcsh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, tcsh

I am trying to convert some of my .bash_profile to be compatible or functionally work in a tcsh environment.  Below are the things I would like to translate/convert:

```
#  Define the IDL base path
#  Note:  I actually source a setup routine that defines these, but if they
#           are not found, I have the IF statement below to handle that
export IDL_LOC ; IDL_LOC=/Applications/itt/idl
export IDL_DIR ; IDL_DIR=/Applications/itt/idl71

unset IDL_PATH
if [ ${IDL_DIR:-0} != 0 ] ; then
  export IDL_PATH ; IDL_PATH=$IDL_DIR
  ##  Make sure to recursively search subdirectories
  IDL_PATH=${IDL_PATH}:$(find $IDL_DIR -type d | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/:$//')
  ##  Add my directories  (extra routines that you probably won't need)
  IDL_PATH=$IDL_PATH:+.:+$HOME/example/directory/one
else
  export IDL_PATH ; IDL_PATH=:+.:+/example/directory/two:+$HOME/example/directory/one
fi

################################################################################
# Set up a function
function themis {
   # unset the IDL_PATH to avoid potential conflicts... (kludgy, I know)
   unset IDL_PATH
   #  Define the TDAS path
   export EXAMPLE_PATH_1=/example/directory/three
   #  source the setup IDL file
   source ${IDL_LOC}/bin/idl_setup.bash
   #  source the another setup paths
   source $EXAMPLE_PATH_1/example/directory/four/setup_file.bash
   #  start IDL (i.e., a programming language environment)
   idl
   #  redefine defaults upon exit from IDL
   source $HOME/.bash_profile
}
```

I am not so much confused by the difference between setenv vs. export as I am with the implementation of a few things. For instance:

1)  Can I leave the recursive search syntax alone (i.e., the find command)?

2)  How do you concatenate directories onto an already defined environment variable in tcsh?

3)  Is concatenation the same as in bash?

4)  Can I source a bash file from tcsh?

5)  If the function can be converted to an alias, then how would I separate the various commands so that all are executed sequentially?

6)  Is there an equivalent for the . command (i.e., current working directory) in tcsh?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `tcsh` doesn't have functions, you can't translate that.

Comment: Although since the function doesn't take any parameters, you could convert it to an alias.

Comment: What's your problem with the first part of the script? Don't you know that `setenv` is how you set environment variables, analogous to `export` in bash?

Comment: @Barmar,  I am not so much confused by the difference between setenv vs. export as I am with the implementation of a few things.  For instance, can I leave the recursive search syntax alone?  How do you concatenate directories onto an already defined environment variable in tcsh?  Is it the same as in bash?  Can I source a bash file from tcsh?

Comment: It would be best if you asked those specific questions in the question, rather than just throw a hunk of code at us and ask for a translation.

Comment: @Barmar, I included more specific questions, per your suggestion.